# Что значит двоеточие в конце ip адреса?

Tags: сеть, ip

Например `0.0.0.0:8888`, `0.0.0.0:9999`, `234.2.2.2:8888`

Comment: после двоеточия задается порт

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.2.3